# Where does MySQL store the information about which tablespace a table belongs to?

Tags: mysql

Where does MySQL store the information about which tablespace a table belongs to?

Ie: if I set `city` table to be stored in `ts2` tablespace:

```
alter table city tablespace ts2;
```

Show table status don't say anything about which tablespace this table belongs:

```
mysql> show table status where name = 'city'\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: city
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Dynamic
           Rows: 4150
 Avg_row_length: 98
    Data_length: 409600
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 81920
      Data_free: 3145728
 Auto_increment: 4080
    Create_time: 2023-06-11 20:19:15
    Update_time: NULL
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8mb4_general_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options:
        Comment:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Neither information_schema.tables

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'city'\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  TABLE_CATALOG: def
   TABLE_SCHEMA: world
     TABLE_NAME: city
     TABLE_TYPE: BASE TABLE
         ENGINE: InnoDB
        VERSION: 10
     ROW_FORMAT: Dynamic
     TABLE_ROWS: 4150
 AVG_ROW_LENGTH: 98
    DATA_LENGTH: 409600
MAX_DATA_LENGTH: 0
   INDEX_LENGTH: 81920
      DATA_FREE: 3145728
 AUTO_INCREMENT: 4080
    CREATE_TIME: 2023-06-11 20:19:15
    UPDATE_TIME: NULL
     CHECK_TIME: NULL
TABLE_COLLATION: utf8mb4_general_ci
       CHECKSUM: NULL
 CREATE_OPTIONS:
  TABLE_COMMENT:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Am I forgetting any table in the data dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tablespaces only applies to InnoDB tables, so this attribute is in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TABLES`.

```
mysql> select name, space from INNODB_TABLES where name like 'test/%';
+-----------------+-------+
| name            | space |
+-----------------+-------+
| test/table1     |   453 |
| test/table2     |   454 |
...
```

See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-information-schema-system-tables.html

Since MySQL 8.0, the InnoDB data dictionary stores metadata about things like tablespaces. You can't query the data dictionary directly, you can only query it indirectly via the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Refer to the documentation I linked to for other I_S views to the data dictionary.